# is there any function to remove the (",") in my code

Tags: java

```
int[] number = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
for (int numb : numb) {

System.out.print(numb);


System.out.print(",");

}
```

need to resolve this in this kind of form

```
10,20,30,40,50
```

without the last character that is used

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The easiest way would be a traditional `for` loop;

```
int[] number = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}; 

for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        System.out.print(",");
    }
    System.out.print(number[i]);
}
```

You might also use a `StringJoiner` or stream concatenation. But that would be more complicated than just using a regular `for` loop as above.

Comment: it works thnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Build that string using a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```
int[] number = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
for (int numb : number)
    joiner.add(String.valueOf(numb));
String s = joiner.toString();

System.out.println(s); // prints: 10,20,30,40,50
```

Comment: Thank you im still new with java so StringJoiner its still new for me but it works amazing thnx

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could handle it.

You could use a "manual" for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {...
```

... and then treat the case of when `i + 1 == number.length` as a special case.

You could also use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), map that to a `Stream` using `mapToObj`, and then collect that stream using [`Collectors.joining(",")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String s = Stream.of(number)
  .mapToObject(Integer::toString)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.print(s);
```

But the easiest way is probably to use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-). That will produce a string with a space after each comma, but you can then do `replaceAll(" ", "")` to remove that.

Comment: Hmm trying to figure what you mean cuz im still knew with java can u write full code ?